# In the ELF spec, what does BA_OS and KE_OS mean?

Tags: elf, abi

In the [ELF spec](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) excerpted from the System V ABI, various functions are referenced as `exec(BA_OS)`, as on page 7 of [1](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf).  Other functions are referenced with `KE_OS`.  What do these `*_OS` symbols mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that page 11 of the [latest base document](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/vol1a.pdf) describes "components of conforming systems", wherein "BA" means "base system", "KE" means "kernel extension" while "OS" means "operating system service routines" and "LIB" means "general library routines".